# How to slide toggle list elements with AngularJS and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to build a clickable drop-down menu. I'm using my own build AngularJS directive to make the drop-down work as well as loading the menu items dynamically.

I've come a far way, but now I have just one little problem.. I can't find a CSS(3) only way to make an animation for the dropping down `ul`'s.

**What I have:**

[image]

**The code for the dropdown function:**

```
private CreateDirective(): any {
        return {
            restirct: 'E',
            scope: {
                dataset: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'App/Templates/LeftBar/index.html',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.Select = Select;

                var SelectedItem;

                function Select(MenuItem: any): any {

                    if (SelectedItem != null) {
                        SelectedItem.selected = false;
                    } 

                    if (MenuItem.open) {
                        MenuItem.selected = true;
                        MenuItem.open = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (MenuItem.childs && MenuItem.childs.length > 0) {
                        MenuItem.open = true;
                    }

                    MenuItem.selected = true;
                    SelectedItem = MenuItem;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone maybe know a replacement of jQuery's `slideToggle` or a way to use jQuery's `slideToggle` in my directive?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language is that written in? because that does not seem like javascript...

Comment: JavaScript combined with TypeScript @Neal

Comment: Then put that in the tags....

Comment: @Neal there we go, I forgot that.. Sorry.

Comment: Please stop putting the tag name in the title...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plain CSS + help from angular to provide ng-class toggling.

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 50px; // your widget width
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
   margin-top: 0;
   -webkit-transition:all .3s ease;
   -moz-transition:all .3s ease;
   -o-transition:all .3s ease;
   transition:all .3s ease;
}
.container.collapsed .content {
  margin-top: -100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="container" ng-class="{'collapsed':!item.open}">
    <ul class="content">
      <li>...</li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Basically this hides UL behind parent LI. By setting negative margin you are driving UL away from parent block thus reducing the size of parent automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate it with just CSS if you animate the max-height:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('nav');
button.onclick = function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'SPAN') return;
  target = target.nextSibling.nextSibling;
  if (target.className === 'open') {
    target.className = '';
  } else {
    target.className = 'open';
  }
};
```

```css
ul {
  display: block;
   transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

ul ul {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul#nav1.open {
  max-height: 50px;
}
ul#nav2.open {
  max-height: 100px;
}
ul#nav3.open {
  max-height: 150px;
}

ul span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <span>Title 1</span>
    <ul id="nav1">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Title 2</span>
    <ul id="nav2">
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
      <li>six</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Title 3</span>
    <ul id="nav3">
      <li>seven</li>
      <li>eight</li>
      <li>nine</li>
      <li>ten</li>
      <li>eleven</li>
      <li>twelve</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that I am using `max-height` instead of `height` so that you don't have to worry about small pixel differences between browsers--but you *will* have to set different heights for each nav option if you want it to animate properly.

Comment: I'm loading the navigation dynamically so there's no standard max-height for the nav options. The items are loaded based on permissions.

Comment: If you're creating the nav dynamically, then you can calculate the height based on the number of elements and set it that way.